# Opening ports with IPTables not working - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall

So, I have these rules set in iptables:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:6850:6999
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpts:6850:6999
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:6881

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Although, the ports are not open :/ here is a telnet attempt:

```
# telnet localhost 6999
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Any idea why this is happening? Do I need to reboot or do someone to make the changes permanent? Last time I rebooted the rules disappeared from iptables :/

Comment: Show the output of `netstat -ntlp | grep 6999`.

Comment: It does not output anything

Comment: Then you have no process listening on port 6999/tcp, which in turn causes the TCP/IP stack to reject the connection attempt. This behavior is by design.

Comment: oh, I am running multiple rTorrent daemons, which should use ports 6881 to 6999 for listening for bitorrent traffic, but it too says the ports are closed, any idea what I need to do?

Comment: Try connecting to a port that actually does have something listening on it and see what result you get then.

Comment: I can telnet onto port 8100 which is the apache port for one of the rTorrent daemons.

Comment: Then there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with iptables. Describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: well IPtables are not used to open port 8100, i assumed apache opened it, the error I simply get from rTorrent is "Port 6881 closed" :/

Comment: Perhaps port 6881 is closed on your border router (or filtered by your ISP)? According to your `iptables -L` output nothing is filtered on your host, and unless you can provide some more information (configuration, network layout, logs, ...) there isn't much anyone can do to help you with this problem.

Comment: Please provide 'iptables-save -c'. Are you behind a NAT enabled router? Sometimes it's possible to port scan (using nmap) a remote host (even if the remote host does not have them ports in use or open) to determine which ports are filtered by your ISP.

Comment: the output of iptables-save -c does not fit :/ so I put it in a pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/1183462/

Comment: nmap does not even show all open ports, like it shows port 8100 as open, but not 8101 which i also open and working fine with apache :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem after all this time :P as I said I was running multiple daemons trying to listen on port 6881, well obviously, only one daemon can listen on that port. So all I had to do was assign a different port to each daemon. :P

Comment: I'm quite scared that nobody seemed to have noticed that your iptables policies aren't actually doing anything. No matter what port you use, connections will be allowed.

Comment: Oh and the reason for this is that your default policy is ACCEPT, and none of your other rules within each chain deny anything.